# how to write apache rewrite rule with parameters?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

when i try to hit the following url it's saying not found

```
 example.com/sample/status/form?to=20
```

but when i use the same url with port like below its working fine this may be because i have deploy 2 artifact on same port

```
        example.com:8080/sample/status/form?to=20
```

because of that i need to write rewrite rule which write like he below one but its not working

```
        RewriteRule ^/status/success/to$    /sample/status/form?to=20
```

the number 20 might change everytime. 
how could i write re-write rule for this?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. It looks like you're running two servers but want to rewrite requests from one the other. This is almost certainly the wrong way to achieve what you want. Give more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Walf ..there is only one server here and two artifacts(projects) one is sample where i want to hit and other is bspro.
 example.com:8080/sample/status/form?to=20 this url works fine i want to use this url without 8080 port number for that i need to write rule

Comment: If it's only one server then why is the second project running on a different port? Why do you think you need to use rewrites? You can't rewrite out ports.

Comment: both running on same port but dont know why i need to provide port number to work this url

Comment: Sorry, you're not providing more info, as requested, and the language barrier is too high.

Comment: If the number 20 "might change every time", how would we go about determining it? A RewriteRule is a formula, and you must know what input it is to expect, as well as what output you want to produce. Can you describe your expected output for us?